# Getting 'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed' but certificate is not expired and working on in other server

Tags: java, oracle, ssl-certificate, weblogic, sha1

We are in process to upgrade our environments and which include weblogic server upgrade as well. Currently we have UAT running on Weblogic 10.3.6 which connect to database from one other application and we use SHA1 certificate for securing the connection.

Now we are upgrading to Weblogic 12.1.3 and using same certificate, server is not able to connect to database and giving below error,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Executing query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM DATAROOM]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; java.security.PrivilegedActionException: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'GOV-UDAM-VIEWER'. The DBMS driver exception was: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver]SSL handshake failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'GOV-UDAM-VIEWER'. The DBMS driver exception was: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver]SSL handshake failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.initializeConnection(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:427)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:402)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:139)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.security.PrivilegedAction
```

As per my understanding this error comes when server is expired but in this case server in valid and moreover our old UAT is able to connect to server.

Please help me to drill down this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but rather a suggestion:

I remember having similar problems some time ago, the solution then was that the system clock on one of the servers (application or DB server, not sure anymore) was not set correctly. This was fixed by repairing the NTP daemon on the server, which for some reason or other stopped working some time before. It could be that the software update enforces stricter checks on the timestamp(s) involved, which causes the problem only to show after updating.

Please note, however, that this was not Java-related, but rather C#, and also a couple of years ago. So it might not apply to your case, or even be partially misremembered by me.